# Reuse templates/steps in different argo workflows

Tags: argo-workflows

Assume having two different argo workflows using the same template `whalesay`:

```yaml
apiVersion: argoproj.io/v1alpha1
kind: Workflow
metadata:
  name: workflow1
spec:
  # invoke the whalesay template with
  # "hello world" as the argument
  # to the message parameter
  entrypoint: whalesay
  arguments:
    parameters:
    - name: message
      value: hello world

  templates:
  - name: whalesay
    inputs:
      parameters:
      - name: message       
    container:
      # run cowsay with that message input parameter as args
      image: docker/whalesay
      command: [cowsay]
      args: ["{{inputs.parameters.message}}"]
```

```yaml
apiVersion: argoproj.io/v1alpha1
kind: Workflow
metadata:
  name: workflow2
spec:
  entrypoint: hello-hello-hello

  templates:
  - name: hello-hello-hello
    # Instead of just running a container
    # This template has a sequence of steps
    steps:
    - - name: hello1            
        template: whalesay
        arguments:
          parameters:
          - name: message
            value: "hello1"
    - - name: hello2a           
        template: whalesay
        arguments:
          parameters:
          - name: message
            value: "hello2a"

  - name: whalesay
    inputs:
      parameters:
      - name: message
    container:
      image: docker/whalesay
      command: [cowsay]
      args: ["{{inputs.parameters.message}}"]
```

Is there a way to avoid repeating (and maintaining) the same template in the two different workflows? Maybe something similar to WorklowTemplate, like:

```yaml
apiVersion: ...
kind: TemplateTemplate
name: whalesay
inputs:
   parameters:
   - name: message
container:
   image: docker/whalesay
   command: [cowsay]
   args: ["{{inputs.parameters.message}}"]
```

```yaml
apiVersion: argoproj.io/v1alpha1
kind: Workflow
metadata:
  name: workflow1
metadata:
  name:
spec:
  entrypoint: whalesay
  arguments:
    parameters:
    - name: message
      value: hello world
  templates:
  - templateRef: whalesay
```

```yaml
apiVersion: argoproj.io/v1alpha1
kind: Workflow
metadata:
  name: workflow2
spec:
  entrypoint: hello-hello-hello

  templates:
  - name: hello-hello-hello
    # Instead of just running a container
    # This template has a sequence of steps
    steps:
    - - name: hello1            
        templateRef: whalesay
        arguments:
          parameters:
          - name: message
            value: "hello1"
    - - name: hello2a           
        templateRef: whalesay
        arguments:
          parameters:
          - name: message
            value: "hello2a"
```

Answer (score 2):

As you guessed correctly, there are [WorkflowTemplates](https://argoproj.github.io/argo-workflows/workflow-templates/) which can be saved in Argo and then reused across other Workflows (or WorkflowTemplates). You had it pretty much running, see:

In Argo, in section Workflow Templates you can add templates (or use command line).
[image]

Inside you paste the template code (below), which then will be discoverable by Workflows (and other WorkflowTemplates).

```yaml
apiVersion: argoproj.io/v1alpha1
kind: WorkflowTemplate
metadata:
  name: whalesay-template
spec:
  entrypoint: runner
  arguments:
    parameters:
    - name: message
      value: hello world
  templates:
  - name: runner
    inputs:
      parameters:
      - name: message       
    container:
      image: docker/whalesay
      command: [ cowsay ]
      args: [ "{{inputs.parameters.message}}" ]
```

and then you can use it in your Workflows (or even in WorkflowTemplates). Copy the code below:

```yaml
apiVersion: argoproj.io/v1alpha1
kind: Workflow
metadata:
  generateName: workflow1-
  labels:
    env: "test"
spec:
  entrypoint: runner
  arguments:
    parameters:
    - name: outer-message
      value: hello CRUEL world
  templates:
    - name: runner
      steps:
      - - name: template-run
          templateRef:
            name: whalesay-template # template name from metadata
            template: runner # inside entrypoint name from template
          arguments:
            parameters:
              - name: message
                value: "{{workflow.parameters.outer-message}}"
      - - name: template-run2
          templateRef:
            name: whalesay-template
            template: runner
          arguments:
            parameters:
              - name: message
                value: hello MAD world
```

and paste it into Workflow Submit form:
[image]

it will create a workflow with generated name, and when it finishes you should see:
[image]

and of course in logs there are expected messages (the ones passed from Workflow, not the one used in WorkflowTemplate):
[image]
[image]

in such way you do need to maintain Workflows, however the common part is in one place only.